# how to reorder the payment methods on front end?

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, payment-methods, render-blocking

In the payment method section I have three options and are in the following order..
1.checkout with credit card
2.Payment with amazon
3.Pay with paypal
And this method is getting rendered by the following code..

```
<div class="cart">
<?php if(!$this->hasError()): ?>
    <ul class="checkout-types contpdng pdngbtm0">
    <?php foreach ($this->getMethods('methods') as $method): ?>
        <?php $methodHtml = $this->getMethodHtml($method); ?>
        <?php if ($methodHtml): ?>
        <li><?php echo $methodHtml; ?></li>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But I want to reorder it like :

1. Pay with paypal
2. Payment with amazon
3. Checkout with credit card
   Could any one suggest how to reorder the payment method in the front end ?

Comment: I can't find the configuration field Sort Order for Crefo Payment.
Where can i add this? layout.xml?? how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Magento already has this feature.**

For every payment method, there is a configuration field name ***Sort Order*** by which you can manage this sort order.

Comment: Can it be possible through layout xml file ?

Comment: @KishorePatra No. But you can configure it per store view.

Comment: Are there same option in magento 2

Comment: Yes,it have....

Answer (score 0):

Check on your xml file for this particular payment method, in my case I was entering an order position but it was ignored by the system. added `after='-'` or `before=''` on the line that inserts the .phtml file used and it worked for the modified payment methods. hope this helps you.